# How to add device orientation to project programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, device-orientation

Is there a way to **add** or **remove** these components programatically?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not exactly. You need to set up all the possible user interface orientations your app's view controllers MIGHT support in info.plist. Once you've done that there are view controller methods the system calls to see what orientations an individual view controller supports. (See `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in the docs.)

As of iOS 8 we're not supposed to use rotation methods any more, so check the docs carefully. It looks to me like `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is still supported, but the `willRotate...`, `willAnimateRotation...`, `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`, etc, are deprecated.

I suggest reading about user interface rotation in the UIViewController class reference (in Xcode or in Apple's online documentation on the web.)

Comment: So is there a way to disable the auto rotation programmatically or not?

Comment: @mafioso: the answer is YES. You can do it just override `shouldAutorotate` function and return NO (to disable) or YES (enable)

Comment: Apple's system for all of this has changed since this thread was opened. I'll try to find time to post an updated answer.